# MySQL optimizations on local server with many databases

Tags: mysql

I'm running a local mysql server for development. I have around 300 databases with about 152 tables per database.

I've noticed that adding so many database has slowed down some queries. I've noticed this happening particularly when I'm migrating a database from the Laravel app.

Is there any configuration I can update to improve the performance locally? I have 32gb of ram so I don't mind it using more resources. I also don't mind if it's something quick and dirty since this is just a local development server.

Comment: "About 152" ???

Comment: Yeah around 152 tables per database. Some sites have a few extra tables so it varies a little

Comment: The number of "databases" (schemas, actually) and tables is not as important for performance as is the number of concurrent active connections.

Comment: Very hard to know with so few info about your environment (you didn't even post what MySQL version or OS are you using) but generally speaking, there are a few main performance killers, innodb_buffer_pool_size, a bunch of variables related to i/o and the type of storage/disk you are using. If you provide ENOUGH info about your server, MAYBE we ban help.

Comment: `SHOW PROCESSLIST` - both at problem and non-problem times might be good?

Comment: `SHOW GLOBAL STATUS` should be able to show some things (usually too big for a question so a pastebin of some sort). What my.cnf do you have currently? Recommend enabling a slow query log and related settings to ensure you capture the slow queries.

Comment: Additional information request. 
RAM size, # cores, any SSD or NVME devices on MySQL Host server? 
Post on pastebin.com and share the links. 
From your SSH login root, Text results of: 
B) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;    after minimum 24 hours UPTIME
C) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES; 
D) SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST;
E) complete MySQLTuner report 
AND Optional helpful information, if available includes - 
htop OR top  for most active apps, 
ulimit -a       for a Linux/Unix list of limits, 
iostat -xm 5 3 for IOPS by device and core/cpu count, 
for server workload tuning analysis to provide suggestions.

Comment: what is size of your database ?

Comment: @DavidMaksimov Please post the complete MySQLTuner report so we can get one answer about the 'size of your database'. The report will summarize by ENGINE, GB of data space and table count. Both of these are important to share with your audience.

Comment: The OS manages 1 directory per database and 1-3 files per table.  This can impact lots-of-table-sites.  How many different tables are touched in, say, an hour?  All?  Just a few db's worth?  Only a few table, but in every db?  Other?

Comment: @RickJames I'm usually working on one site at a time. I've really only noticed performance issues when running migrations (creating tables, columns, renaming, etc). I've noticed that it takes longer especially when running rename operations.